# std::sort on vector of shared pointers

Tags: c++

I have a class cBin whose constructor assigns a unique id.

I have a vector of shared pointers to bins.

```
typedef std::shared_ptr< cBin > bin_t;
```

I have a class  cPackEngine with an attribute that is the vector of shared pointers to bins and a method that returns a reference to the vector

```
std::vector< bin_t > & bins()
{
    return myBin;
}
...
std::vector< bin_t > myBin;
```

I use `std::sort` to arrange the order of bins in the vector

```
void SortBinsIntoIncreasingSize( cPackEngine& e )
{

    sort( e.bins().begin(), e.bins().end(),
          []( bin_t a, bin_t b )
    {
        ...
```

This usually works well.  But occasionally, for certain inputs, the application crashes in the sort.

The debugger shows that this occurs when the lambda function returns after processing a and b that are pointing to the **exact same** bin.  So I added this:

```
sort( e.bins().begin(), e.bins().end(),
      []( bin_t a, bin_t b )
{
    std::cout << "compare\n" << a->text() << b->text();
    if( a->progID() == b->progID() ) {
        std::cout << "!!!\n" << a->text() << b->text();
        std::cout << " a points to " << a.get() << " has use count " << a.use_count() << "\n";
        std::cout << " b points to " << b.get() << " has use count " << b.use_count() << "\n";
        throw std::runtime_error( "SortBinsIntoIncreasingSize");
    }
```

The output is

```
compare
CENPLY6_GREY_GREY  95 5760x180 at 5760 12020
CENPLY6_GREY_GREY  65 3760x440 at 19760 11760
compare
CENPLY6_GREY_GREY  95 5760x180 at 5760 12020
CENPLY6_GREY_GREY  93 5760x180 at 0 12020
compare
CENPLY6_GREY_GREY  95 5760x180 at 5760 12020
CENPLY6_GREY_GREY  95 5760x180 at 5760 12020
!!!
CENPLY6_GREY_GREY  95 5760x180 at 5760 12020
CENPLY6_GREY_GREY  95 5760x180 at 5760 12020
 a points to 0x2a30740 has use count 3
 b points to 0x2a30740 has use count 3
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  SortBinsIntoIncreasingSize
```

95 is the ID of the bin that is involved in the crash.  I check that there is only one bin 95 in the vector by dumping the vector just before the call to sort

```
for( auto it = e.bins().begin(); it != e.bins().end(); it++ )
    std::cout << (*it)->text();
```

Note: Returning true whan a and b point to same object still crashes:

```
    sort( e.bins().begin(), e.bins().end(),
          []( bin_t a, bin_t b )
    {
        std::cout << "compare\n" << a->text() << b->text();
        if( a->progID() == b->progID() ) {
//            std::cout << "!!!\n" << a->text() << b->text();
//            std::cout << " a points to " << a.get() << " has use count " << a.use_count() << "\n";
//            std::cout << " b points to " << b.get() << " has use count " << b.use_count() << "\n";
//            throw std::runtime_error( "SortBinsIntoIncreasingSize");

            return true;
```

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: @eerorika Not possible.  Minimal examples do not crash.  Only a few rare cases using the entire application crash.

Comment: Then nobody will be able to help you, without a [mre], and this should be closed as off-topic. I've been on stackoverflow.com less than half as long as you are, and even I know that.

Comment: @ravenspoint: Then how can you expect someone to debug it?

Comment: I do not expect anyone to debug it.  I am looking for suggestions for why it may not work

Comment: Note that you compare smart-pointers, rather than the pointees, so the values of bin_t instances seem to be irrelevant here. You're probably focused on a "red herring", the actual problem is in some other place.

Comment: Oh, it's obvious why it does not work: there's a bug somewhere. Just because the sort crashes here, in certain situtations, doesn't mean this is where the problem is. C++ does not work this way. The bug can be anywhere in the code that executes up to the point the sort occurs, where undefined behavior, such as a wild pointer dereference, an array out of bounds access, or something of this sort corrupts memory subtly. The application doesn't crash but continues to run until you get to the sort part, where the earlier corruption finally results in a crash. This is why an [mre] is required.

Comment: You don't even show the content of the lambda. One can only guess with this lack of information. Unrelated: Passing the shared_ptr by value to the lambda will slow down your program significantly. Pass by const reference.

Comment: ", it's obvious why it does not work: there's a bug somewhere."  I love it!  I should post this as an answer to every question in stackoverflow and ammass a million points.  ( Seriously, I am aware of this as is every other competent coder )

Comment: `the application crashes in the sort` - how does it crash? Do you get any exception or just simple "segmentation fault"? The `[]( bin_t a, bin_t b )` shouldn't it be `[](const bin_t& a, const bin_t&  b )`? What does it mean "stops dead"? If it stops, ie. the program terminates, what is the exit status of the program?

Comment: No, this wouldn't be an answer to every question on stackoverflow.com, only the ones seeking debugging help, but without a [mre].

Comment: Stops dead.  The debugger shows a halt in atomicity.h

Comment: @ravenspoint what if you return `false` instead of `true`?

Comment: You should show the full lambda

Answer (score 1):

> processing a and b that are pointing to the exact same bin

There is no guarantee that `std::sort` *won't* compare an object to itself. Your comparison function therefore needs to return that the "two" objects are the same.

---

> ```
>         return true;
> ```

`std::sort` requires that the comparison functor provide a *strict, weak ordering*. If the same object compares as `true` to itself, then that's not a [strict ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#Strict_and_non-strict_partial_orders). So you violated the rules of `sort` and therefore get a runtime crash.

Comment: I have tried that.  Still crashes.

Comment: @ravenspoint: Not according to the code in your question. The code in your question as written says "I will crash if I compare an object to itself". If that's not your intent, then don't write it that way.

Comment: I have added the code returning true to my question.  Still crashes.

Comment: @ravenspoint: What do you mean "code returning true"? I don't see *any* `return` statement in your code. I don't even see an edit history of your question, which would indicate that you've edited your question.

Comment: Then the information in your question is inaccurate/out of date. You should update and the tell us when it crashes now since it cannot crash anymore when comparing two equal elements.

Comment: I have edited the question!

Comment: @ravenspoint: See the edit in my answer.

Comment: @Nicol Sorry, I do not understand.  Can you clarify, please.

Comment: Returning false fixes the crash!

Comment: @ravenspoint: Are you asking me to explain what "[strict, weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering)" means? I mean, those are terms you can use Google to track down. Or even just look at the [requirements of `std::sort`'s comparison function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).

Comment: The simple, practical, usable answer is to return 'false".  There is no 'return that the two objects are the same'.  A lot of mumbo jumbo about weak ordering just confuses the issue.  Since you have rolled back my edit, please edit your answer yourself so that it is actually useful.

Comment: @ravenspoint: "*The simple, practical, usable answer is to return 'false". There is no 'return that the two objects are the same'.*" That's exactly why I said it like that. So that the reader could go do the research on the concept of "strict, weak orderings" and discover for yourself that the way such an ordering defines "the same" is that `comp(a,b)` and `comp(b,a)` are both `false`. Otherwise, I'm just giving you code to copy-and-paste into your program, which is generally not something I prefer to do. If you want to provide a copy-and-paste answer, you are free to do so.

Comment: @ravenspoint: I'm not sure I understand your point in this regard. Your problem was because you didn't understand the theoretical basis for what you were trying to do. Are you honestly saying that it is *better* for you to get a one-line fix for this specific issue than to actually understand *why* that fixes it or the theory behind what returning `false` actually means? You sound like you're suggesting that there's some practical benefit to remaining ignorant of the meaning of your code.

Comment: At your request I have provided the complete, fixed, lambda code.

Comment: @ravenspoint: Answers go in the *answer* section. It's OK to answer your own question, but not *in the question*.